# AWS EC2 update without downtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there anyway I can update my application in EC2 without any downtime? Or something like pausing but not restarting

Comment: question is too broad. you should put in more details around how you app looks like and how you're trying to deploy

Answer (score 3):

If you only have a single EC2 instance and your app is web application, you can dockerize your app and use any web proxy to switch over between docker container with zero downtime.

Let say your app is in docker container A:

```
Internet --> Nginx Proxy --> Container A
```

When you update your app, you need to deploy it on a new container B:

```
Internet --> Nginx Proxy --> Container A
                             Container B
```

Reconfigure your proxy to switch over to container B, in Nginx, you can `service nginx reload` without killing Nginx:

```
Internet --> Nginx Proxy     Container A
                        `--> Container B
```

Remove your older container A:

```
Internet --> Nginx Proxy --> Container B
```

And, you have a zero downtime deployment.

Take a look also into my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/33085105/3427434. The script in there, does the same thing that I told in here.

Answer (score 2):

[AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) can be used to achieve this.

The idea, as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html), is to create a new environment with the latest version of your app, and once deployed, swap the CNAMEs of your current production environment and the newly deployed one, thereby achieving zero-downtime.